# Manage same repository with both Gitlab and Gogs

Tags: git, gitlab, gogs

Let's assume I have a repository created using gitlab community edition (hosted on my server) and now, I want to be able to interact with the same repository also using Gogs (https://gogs.io)

How can I do that without having to import the repository again? Is there any way to manage the same repository through both systems?

I saw repository mirroring feature in Gitlab but it is not available in community edition. Any alternative approach?

Comment: I'm having trouble thinking of any reason to do this. What's your goal?

Comment: @Chris We are evaluating version control systems to be setup in the organization I work at. While I can go for either Gitlab or gogs to start with, I wanted to know if it was possible to seamlessly switch between platforms without having to do any deployment or migration incase a platform does not seem to work out for us at some point in time.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not aware of any way to do what you want. Maybe set some repos up in one and some in the other?